# WPF ListBox Binding Performance issue

Tags: wpf, performance, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection

I have a `ListBox` which has a `DataTemplate` applied to the items. Each item is to display 3 text fields. The `ListBox` is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. Everything is working fine, but when I try to load more than ~100 items into the collection, it starts chewing up all my CPU and takes ages to load.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post the Xaml for your DataTemplate

Comment: Can we see your implementation for adding to the collection as well as for INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

try using VirtualizingStackPanel

Please refer this document may that can help you
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/recycling-that-item-container)

Comment: ListBox already has the VirtualizingStackPanel. Its IsVirtualizing is also set to true by default. However the VirtualizationMode could be set to Recycling to reuse items. But wonder if that could be the problem for loading just 100+ items.